# Json converter change date format while deserializing

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have json where date is defined like this;

`{\"$date\":\"1947-11-13T00:00:00.000Z\"}`

and my deserilising code look like this:

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<U>(szResp,
                     new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" 
});
```

The object I'm creating is just

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$date")]
    public string date { get; set; }
```

but instead of **13/11/1947 00:00:00** 
I'm receiving : **11/13/1947 00:00:00**

I have no clues why this deserilizer behaves like this and changes data format.

More over if I try to see data in Json visualizer in visual studio my date is shown properly **"13/11/1947 12:00:00 πμ"**

Comment: if your json says 1947 why would you expect your code to turn it into 2006?

Comment: The date you gave as an example is the 11/13/1947, why do you expect 24/06/2006 ?

Comment: How do you print out the date? Can you show that part of the code as well? I assume the date is correct you only use the wrong date format when printing out.

Comment: This date is not printed. I put breakpoint after deserializing and check data inside object.

Comment: Well the date has the correct value, the date format however is dependent on the culture info you have set in your program, most likely the culture info has the default date format as MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: I double checked it. Regional settings are set to dd/MM/yyyy. Question more over why it changes data while deserilizing from string to the string? Shouldn't it be just 1-1?